# Web analytics SQL table design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, analytics

I'm trying to design tables for some basic web analytics (without using google analytics).

I want to record: views, time on page, browser, platform and country on each page.

My idea was to have the following tables and add one row in each for each page and just increment the values.

**Pages:** Id,Page,Views,TimeOnPage,BrowserId,PlatformId,CountryId

**Browsers:** Id,PageId,Chrome,Msie,Firefox,Safari,Opera,Other

**Platforms:** Id,PageId,Windows,OSX,Android,iOS,Linux,Other

**Counteries:** Id,PageId,[all countries as columns]

The thinking behind this was that if there is many thousands of pages views, there will only be one row per page per table. The problem is how do I add a country field to this data? If followed the same design, I would need a country table with 195 columns, add one row per page and increment the country column corresponding to the view. But that doesn't seem like a good design, maybe with a small number of pages, but what if there are hundreds of pages?

The alternative seems to be to create a session table.

**Pages:** Id,Page

**Session:** Id,PageId,TimeOnPage,BrowserId,PlatformId,CountryId

**Browsers:** Id,Browser

**Platforms:** Id,Platform

**Countries:** Id,Countries

But I'm concerned about the size of the session table over time.
With a a few hundred pages, assuming a popular site, the session table could grow very quickly. So then the max Id range becomes a problem. Would it be better to use a GUID for the Id column? But still, it doesn't seem like a good design if the session table is going to have so many rows?
I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this or what the best way to do this is? Some guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The normal design is to maintain a record of each page and then to -- possibly -- aggregate them into sessions.  This starts with the reference tables:

- `Pages`:  PageId, URL, . . . (one row per possible page)
- `Browsers`: BrowserId, BrowserName, . . . (one row per platform)
- `Platforms`: PlatformId, PlatformName, . . . (one row per platform)
- `Countries`: CountryId, CountryName, . . . (one row per country)

Note that adding new pages, browsers, etc. is trivial.  You just add a new rows to the tables.

Then you would normally have:

- `PageViews`:  PageView, PageId, BrowserId, PlatformId, CountryId, datetime, . . .

And probably:

- `SessionPages`:  SessionId, PageViewId
- `Sessions`:  SessionId, . . .

The definition of session depends on business requirements (and typically experience with your site).

Yes, the data will be big.  That is why you are storing it in a database.  You will have the detailed data so you can investigate what has happened in more detail than your pre-summarized approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to add the PageViews table with details of each view for a specific page and then aggregate the data on an analytics page.

Considering PageViews (depending on number of pages, popularity and time) may contain billions of rows, what is the best way to implement such a table. NoSql? Azure table? Partitioned tables? Indexing?